# LUKS passphrase over ssh is not working

Tags: ssh, encryption

I followed [stinky parkia's guide to unlocking device over ssh](https://stinkyparkia.wordpress.com/2014/10/14/remote-unlocking-luks-encrypted-lvm-using-dropbear-ssh-in-ubuntu-server-14-04-1-with-static-ipst/).

However, the password is not working. I am able to reach the shell to enter the passphrase but it's simply not accepting the correct password and keeps telling me `cryptsetup: cryptsetup failed, bad password or options?`, I type the same password with a keyboard attached directed with the Pi4 and it works.

I little more research showed `initramfs` option is required in `crypttab`.
Updated `crypttab`:

```
# <target name> <source device>     <key file>  <options>
sdcard  /dev/mmcblk0p2  none    luks,initramfs
```

However, the password is still not working over SSH.

Any hints on what I am possibly doing wrong?

Details:

1. uname -a: Linux raspi 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT aarch64
2. OS: Raspberry OS lite
3. cryptsetup --version: cryptsetup 2.3.7

Comment: Update: Found similar instructions on a [linuxconfig.org's blog](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-unlock-a-luks-volume-on-boot-on-raspberry-pi-os), same problem.

Comment: Does the password have any characters which could be confused by differing encoding/keyboard layouts? Does connecting to it over SSH work from a different machine? (that isn't a RPI, or that is running a general purpose OS, like Ubuntu Desktop)

Comment: @Ashley; Already checked about the encoding problem; that's not it. Tried printing all characters in plain text, and the password was correct; secondly, yes, connecting to SSH is no problem, from any machine (tried multiple machines), just entering the password wouldn't work.

Comment: I meant when you connect the drive to another machine, can you successfully enter the password over SSH to that machine?

Comment: I have one RPi and other machines are amd64. Testing that arm64 OS on other machines will not be possible.